# VUE / VUEX: How To Pass Data From Parent Template To Child Template

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Using **VUE 2.0** and **VUEX** I am a bit confused about how to pass data from `parent` to `child`.

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <div class="card" v-for="(triad, index) in triads">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <people />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <places />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <equipment />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am *looping* through an array named "triads":

```
state: {
  triads: [
    {
      people: [],
      places: [],
      equipment: []
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to send the `triad` variable to `<people />`, `<places />` and `<equipment />`.

---

How do I get the content from the **parent template** to the **child template**? Thank you.

Comment: Are people,places and equipment seperate components?

Comment: yes they are ;-) I just want to distribute the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add PROP to your child components and then bind data.

E.g. `<people :yourProp='triad'>`

In your child components (as per docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props):

```
Vue.component('people', {
  // declare the props
  props: ['yourProp'],
  // just like data, the prop can be used inside templates
  // and is also made available in the vm as this.message
  template: '<span>{{ yourProp }}</span>'
})
```

you do not need vuex to just pass data. You need Vuex to share states between components (bi-directional).

Comment: well, could you explain it in more depth? i am quite new to vue and vuex. but thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can pass the properties down by the means of props

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <div class="card" v-for="(triad, index) in triads">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <people :someproperty='triad'></people>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <places :someproperty='triad'></places>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <equipment :someproperty='triad'></equipement>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

and inside each of these children components, mention the props like so:

```
export default {
  props: ['someproperty']
}
```

---

I think your parent component too doesnt have access to the property directly, so you could use mapGetters in the parent to have access to it, at the same time, it follows that your state too has a getter.

```
state: {
  triads: [
    {
      people: [],
      places: [],
      equipment: []
    }
  ]
},
getters: {
  getTriads: (state) => {
     return state.triads
  }
}
```

---

Now, you can use [mapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html) in your parent:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      'triads': 'getTriads'
    })
  }
}
```

If that is too much of a setup, just try this

```
export default {
  computed: {
    triads () {
     /**
     * You could also try, return this.$store.state.triads
     * but DONT do that, that defeats the purpose of using vuex.  
     */
      return this.$store.getters.getTriads 
    }
  }
}
```